# Show custom validation message if any of 4 inputs are missing

Tags: jquery, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a payment form on my site with credit card info and billing address.  There are 4 input boxes in the credit card section.  I don't want individual validation messages next to each of those.  Instead I want a single message below the credit card that says something like "Please fill in all the credit card information".  This is using jquery validation with MVC4.

Here is my form:

```
    <div class="creditcard form-group">
      <h2>Credit Card</h2>
      @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.cardNumber, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "CardNum", @placeholder = "Card Number" })
      @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.name, new { @class = "form-control cap", @id = "FullName", @placeholder = "Full Name" })
      @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.expDate, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "CardExp", @placeholder = "MM/YY" })
      @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.cvv, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "CardCVV", @placeholder = "CVV" })
      @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ccType)
    </div>
    <h2>Billing Address</h2>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="checkbox" id="sameAddress" name="sameAddress" class="checkbox-inline" />
      <label for="sameAddress" class="check">Check if the same as Delivery Address</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.address, new { @class = "col-sm-7" })
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.address, new { @class = "form-control cap" })
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-7">
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.address)
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.address2, new { @class = "col-sm-7" })
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.address2, new { @class = "form-control cap" })
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-7">
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.address2)
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.city, new { @class = "col-sm-7" })
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.city, new { @class = "form-control cap" })
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-7">
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.city)
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.state, new { @class = "col-sm-7" })
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.state, Model.stateList, new { @class = "form-control cap" })
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-7">
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.state)
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.zip, new { @class = "col-sm-7" })
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.zip, new { @class = "form-control cap" })
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-7">
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.zip)
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <div class="buttons">
    <a href="@Url.Action("Delivery", "Cart")">
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" id="back" value="Back">
    </a>
    <input type="submit" value="Next" id="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" />
  </div>
```

Let me know if you need any other code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to handle this manually, as there's no data annotation, etc., that can handle this for you. Client-side, you can use [jQuery Validation's `require_from_group` validation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/require_from_group-method).

Server-side (you should never rely on client-side validation, alone), you can do something like the following in your action:

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.cardNumber) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.name) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.expDate) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.cvv))
{
    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Please fill out all the credit card fields.");
}

if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    ...
```

That will add a general error to the form, which will be shown where you call:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
```

You can also change the `""` parameter to a particular field name to attach the error to that field. For example:

```
ModelState.AddModelError("cardNumber", "Please fill out all the credit card fields.");
```

Would display the error where you call:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.cardNumber)
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm handling the server side errors already.  It was the jquery validation that I needed help with.  I will look into the require_from_group method.  The validate method must be called automatically in MVC; I don't have any specific call to it.  Correct?

Comment: Yes, it's called by the included validation scripts. You just need to add a rule for this, and the existing validation setup should work as always. Also bear in mind that you'll need to make all these fields not required or else they'll still get their own individual validation.